# Realurl-Configuration for news-Extensi

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, realurl, tx-news

I have an problem with the news-configuration for realurl.
TYPO3:   7.6.11
realurl: 2.1.4
news:    5.2.0

I created the following realurl_conf.php. (http://pastebin.com/GsYVaaDr):

```
<?php
// realurl naming precedence configuration
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['addRootLineFields'] .= 'tx_realurl_pathsegment,alias,title';

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['p372493.mittwaldserver.info'] = array(
    'init' => array(
        'enableCHashCache' => true,
        'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
        'adminJumpToBackend' => true,
        'enableUrlDecodeCache' => true,
        'enableUrlEncodeCache' => true,
        'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
        // Allow for proper SEO 404 handling
        'postVarSet_failureMode' => ''
    ),

    'redirects'  => array(),
    'preVars' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'nc' => 1
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'valueMap' => array(
                // Sprachvariable Deutsch
                'de' => '0',
            ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
    ),
    // PAGEPATH mit Standard-Realurl-Konfiguration
    'pagePath' => array(
        'type'   => 'user',
        'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
        'spaceCharacter' => '-',
        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
        'rootpage_id'  => 1,
        'expireDays' => 30,
        // Nimmt Sysordner aus der Rootline (aktuell auskommentiert!)
        'excludeDoktypes' => '254',
        'segTitleFieldList' => 'tx_realurl_pathsegment,alias,title'
    ),
    'fixedPostVars' => array(
        'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'detail' => '',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'News' => '',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),

            'dateFilter' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_newss_pi1[year]',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_newss_pi1[month]',
                    'valueMap' => array (
                        'january' => '01',
                        'february' => '02',
                        'march' => '03',
                        'april' => '04',
                        'may' => '05',
                        'june' => '06',
                        'july' => '07',
                        'august' => '08',
                        'september' => '09',
                        'october' => '10',
                        'november' => '11',
                        'december' => '12',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_newss_pi1[day]',
                ),
            ),

            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                    'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                    'id_field' => 'uid',
                    'alias_field' => 'title',
                    'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                    'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                    'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                        'strtolower' => 1,
                        'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                    ),
                    'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                    'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                    'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                    'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                    'autoUpdate' => 1,
                    'expireDays' => 180,
                ),
            ),
        ), 
    ),
    'postVarSets' => array(
        '_DEFAULT' => array(

            // NEWS
           'newsCategoryConfiguration' => array(
               array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'sys_category',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'newsTagConfiguration' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            '28' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
#           '701' => 'newsDetailConfiguration', // For additional detail pages, add their uid as well
#           '71' => 'newsTagConfiguration',
#           '72' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',           

            'controller' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
            ),

//          'archiv' => array(
//              'GETvar' => '',
//              noMatch => 'bypass'
//          ),
        // NEWS
        ),
    ),
    'fileName' => array (
        'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => true,
        'index' => array(
            'sitemap.xml' => array(
                'keyValues' => array(
                    'type' => 841132,
                ),
            ),
            'feed.rss' => array(
                'keyValues' => array(
                    type => 9818,
                ),
            ),
            'calender.ical' => array (
                'keyValue' => array(
                    type => 9819,
                ),
            ),

            'robots.txt' => array(
                'keyValues' => array(
                    'type' => 841133
                ),
            ),

            'drucken.html' => array(
                'keyValues' => array(
                    'type' => '98',
                    'print' => '1'
                ),
            ),

            'index.html' => array(
                'keyValues' => array(
                    'type' => '0',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => true,
        'acceptHTMLsuffix' => true,
    ),

);
?>
```

I configured the News plugin as follows.

```
plugin.tx_news {
  settings {
    backPid = 25
    listPid = 25

    detail {
      showPrevNext = 1
      showSocialShareButtons = 0
    }

    list {
      media {
        image >
        image {
          maxWidth = 75
          maxHeight = 75
        }
      }
    }

    link {
      skipControllerAndAction = 1
      hrDate = 1
      hrDate {
        day = d
        month = m
        year = Y
      }
    }    

    paginate {
      itemsPerPage = 10
      insertAbove = 1
      insertBelow = 1
      templatePath =
      prevNextHeaderTags = 1
      maximumNumberOfLinks = 3
    }

    analytics.social {
      facebookLike = 0
      facebookShare = 0
      twitter = 0
    }
  }
  predefine.archive = +1 Month
}
```

This configuration issues addresses in the following form:

> /nachricht/detail/News/news-title/archiv/2016/september.html?tx_news_pi1%5Bday%5D=2&cHash=bc08b3c694b77edd4d3de72396906807

but I need address output like this form:

> /nachricht/detail/News/2016/09/02/news-title.html

nachricht is the title of the page.
The basic configuration of realurl running fine.

Someone has an idea or can tell me, how to update my news part of the configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change the 'enableCHashCache' => true to 'enableCHashCache' => FALSE  in your realurl_conf.php for remove cHash=.... from your url. and change below code in postVatSets array for realurl. Try this solution and let me know your feedback. This code works for me.

```
'postVarSets' => array(
        '_DEFAULT' => array(
            //archive
            'period' => array (
                array (
                    'condPrevValue' => -1,
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[pS]',
                    //'valueMap => array()
                    ),
                array (
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[pL]',
                    //'valueMap => array()
                    ),

                array (
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[arc]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'non-archived' => -1,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            'archive' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[year]' ,
                        ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[month]' ,
                            'valueMap' => array(
                            'january' => '01',
                            'february' => '02',
                            'march' => '03',
                            'april' => '04',
                            'may' => '05',
                            'june' => '06',
                            'july' => '07',
                            'august' => '08',
                            'september' => '09',
                            'october' => '10',
                            'november' => '11',
                            'december' => '12',
                            )
                        ),
                    ),

            'browse' => array (
                array (
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[pointer]',
                    ),
                ),
            'select' => array (
                array (
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[cat]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array (
                        'table'     =>  'tt_news_cat',
                        'id_field'  =>  'uid',
                        'alias_field'   =>  'title',
                        'addWhereClause'=>  'AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache'=>  1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf'   =>  array (
                            'strtolower'        =>  1,
                            'spaceCharacter'    =>  '-',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            'article' => array( 

                array (
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[tt_news]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array (
                        'table'     =>  'tt_news',
                        'id_field'  =>  'uid',
                        'alias_field'   =>  'title',
                        'addWhereClause'=>  'AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache'=>  1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf'   =>  array (
                            'strtolower'        =>  1,
                            'spaceCharacter'    =>  '-',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Hi Vimal, I was on holiday and I try your config tomorow evening and give you an response. Thanks for your feedback and I'll hope it will be helpful for my problem.

Comment: okay, Let you try first and let me know solution is work or not.

Comment: Thx, wirh this snipped I was able to configure the date-pointer of my news-EXT. It was helpful.